# How to use arrays created by loop? Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, for-loop, while-loop

The code I'm using imports data from multiple files and saves them into an array of cells, the code is as follows:

```
[FileName,PathName,FilterIndex] = uigetfile('*.txt*','MultiSelect','on');
numfiles = size(FileName,2);
FileData= cell(1,numfiles);
for ii = 1:numfiles
    FileName{ii};
    A=[];
    entirefile =fullfile(PathName,FileName{ii});
    fid = fopen(entirefile);
    tline = fgets(fid);
    while ischar(tline)
        parts = textscan(tline, '%f;');
        if numel(parts{1}) > 0
            A = [ A ; parts{:}' ];
        end
        tline = fgets(fid);
    end
    fclose(fid);
    FileData{ii} = A;

    A = FileData{ii};
    X = A(:,1);
    Y = A(:,5);
    DataToUse = [X,Y];
end
```

Now my issue is I want to use the first `DataToUse` created by the loop, which will be data from the first file, seperatley to the other files but I can not issolate it. I have tried `DataToUse(1)`, `DataToUse(1,1)` and `DataToUse(:,[1,2])` but none are working for me. An example of the type of data would be:

DataToUse=

```
0.0762    0.0271
0.0763    0.2671
0.0764    0.4079
0.0765    0.0510
0.0766    0.0087
0.0767    0.0099
0.0768    0.0067
0.0769    0.0047
0.0770    0.0047
0.0771    0.0349
0.0772    0.2094
0.0773    0.2740
0.0774    0.0294
0.0775    0.0100
0.0776    0.0159
```

I have different numbers of this kind of data depending on how many files are selected but I would like to only use the first initially and use the others later. Anybody know how I can go about doing this? Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use cell arrays, like so:

```
DataToUse{ii} = [X, Y]
```

To get the desired output put this after your for-loop:

```
firstLoopXY = DataToUse{1}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: thank you! Works almost perfectly but for some reason it is giving me the information twice. Any idea how to stop this?

Comment: It actually gives me the data the same number of times as the number of files slected to upload and import data from. Perhaps to do with `DataToUse{ii}`?

Comment: Are you new to programming generally? It's totally ok if you are, I'm just asking because I want to be extra precise if you're new at this. It's important to understand exactly how for-loops work: each statement inside the loop will be executed once for each integer in the range [1, numfiles]. So, if you put `firstLoopXY = DataToUse{1}` inside the for-loop, it will execute once per file, as you described. If you put it after the 'end' at the bottom of your for-loop, it will execute just once. Incidentally, if you put `DataToUse{ii}` in the loop, it would display **that** files data each time.

Comment: Yes I am, pretty much trying to teach myself! Thanks a lot for that help its cleared things up a bit for me @Fletch

Comment: @user3580436, Always a pleasure, and welcome to coding! Build out your profile and stay a while; this is a great place to learn.  Also, don't forget to click the little green check next to the answer to mark it as the solution to your question. Good luck!